# Custom url for a single page

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

Created a page and the link is like the following

```
http://www.demo.com/?page_id=1081
```

need to be like the following

```
http://www.demo.com/phones
```

I need this structure only for this page .So i don't want to change the current permalink structure.Is there any other option to achieve this?

Can anyone help please.

Comment: Can you use .htaccess for this?

Comment: @M-R yes i can,but i don't have much idea about .htaccess

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Comment: @BradDalton Tried m-r's answer but no luck:(

Comment: What have YOU coded so far? What work have you done so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read on [htaccess](http://htaccess-guide.com/). You can try this,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^phones$ /?page_id=1081 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: sorry didn't worked :( my wordpress installed path is` /var/www/html/demo`.

Comment: Check the updated. Its tested and working. I would recommend to read about htaccess as its an awesome thing to work on. :)

Comment: On my server /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file, 'AllowOverride' was set to 'None' changed that to 'All' and your code worked.Thanks!!